# Mi botón no vacía los TextField adecuadamente

Tags: java, textfield

Estoy programando con la librería awt de java y tengo un botón que sirve para vaciar los TextField de manera que cuando se pulsa el botón se ejecuta tx1.setText("");

Cuando utilizo los textfield con otro botón para realizar cualquier operación y luego pulso el botón limpiar se vacía correctamente pero si no le doy a nada anteriormente no se hace.

```
Button btnAceptar = new Button ("Aceptar");
Button btnLimpiar = new Button ("Limpiar");
TextField tx1 = new TextField (10);
TextField tx2 = new TextField (10);

public Registro()
{
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setSize(200,120);
    add(lblogin1);
    add(tx1);
    add(lblogin2);
    add(tx2);
    tx2.setEchoChar('*');
    add(btnAceptar);
    btnAceptar.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnLimpiar);
    btnLimpiar.addActionListener(this);
    addWindowListener(this);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Registro();
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(btnLimpiar.equals(e.getSource()))
    {
        tx1.setText("");
        tx2.setText("");
    }
```

Comment: De favor exponer el código en donde se produce el error, así no te podremos dar solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo tuve el mismo problema y de casualidad encontré una forma de hacerlo posible. Consiste en añadir una línea de código antes de la de **`setText("")`**, y que es **`getText()`**. Mira el código:

```
@Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
    if(btnLimpiar.equals(e.getSource()))
    {
        tx1.getText(); tx2.getText(); // Ésta linea permite que setText("") funcione

        tx1.setText("");
        tx2.setText("");
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por responder!! aunque un poquito tarde xdd. En vez de hacer tx1.getText() es más correcto hacer tx1.selectAll()

Comment: Hola @Coke, si conseguiste resolver el problema, por favor comparte una respuesta con cómo lo hiciste. De ese modo otros usuarios que puedan encontrarse con el mismo problema en el futuro, tendrán una referencia.